# Flash create comma from number performance

Tags: performance, flash

I wrote a small function that splits a number to commas but I have to run over the number too many times. Can you sugest me a better way to do this?

```
public static function getCommaString(value:Number):String {
  var stringValue:String = value.toString();
  if (stringValue.length <= 3) {
    return stringValue;
  }
  var i:int = stringValue.length % 3;
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 3;
  }
  for (; i < stringValue.length; i += 4 ) {
    var part1:String = stringValue.substr(0, i);
    var part2:String = stringValue.substr(i, stringValue.length);
    stringValue = part1.concat(",", part2);
  }
  return stringValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put together a testing class that compares your solution and others, including a solution from this [blog post](http://www.cgiinteractive.com/blog/2009/05/formatting-numbers-with-commas-in-as3/) and solutions from this related [StackExchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721304/insert-commas-into-number-string/) and formatted them in a consistent way for easy comparison:

```
package
{
    public class CommaNumberSolutions
    {   
        public static function commaify( input:Number ):String
        {
            var split:Array = input.toString().split( '.' ),
                front:String = split[0],
                back:String = ( split.length > 1 ) ? "." + split[1] : null,
                n:int = input < 0 ? 2 : 1,
                commas:int = Math.floor( (front.length - n) / 3 ),
                i:int = 1;

            for ( ; i <= commas; i++ )
            {
                n = front.length - (3 * i + i - 1);
                front = front.slice( 0, n ) + "," + front.slice( n );
            }

            if ( back )
                return front + back;
            else
                return front;
        }

        public static function getCommaString( input:Number ):String
        {
            var s:String = input.toString();

            if ( s.length <= 3 )
                return s;

            var i:int = s.length % 3;

            if ( i == 0 )
                i = 3;

            for ( ; i < s.length; i += 4 )
            {
                var part1:String = s.substr(0, i);
                var part2:String = s.substr(i, s.length);
                s = part1.concat(",", part2);
            }

            return s;
        }

        public static function formatNumber( input:Number ):String
        {
            var s:String = input.toString()
            var result:String = ''

            while ( s.length > 3 )
            {
                var chunk:String = s.substr(-3)
                s = s.substr(0, s.length - 3)
                result = ',' + chunk + result
            }

            if ( s.length > 0 )
                result = s + result

            return result
        }

        public static function commaCoder( input:Number ):String
        {
            var s:String = "";
            var len:Number = input.toString().length;

            for ( var i:int = 0; i < len; i++ )
            { 
                if ( (len-i) % 3 == 0 && i != 0)
                    s += ",";

                s += input.toString().charAt(i);
            }
            return s;
        }

        public static function regex1( input:Number ):String
        {
            return input.toString().replace( /-{0,1}(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+$)/g, "$1," );
        }

        public static function regex2( input:Number ):String
        {
            return input.toString().replace( /-{0,1}\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g , "$&,")
        }

        public static function addCommas( input:Number ):String
        {
            var negative:String = "";
            if ( input < 0 )
            {
                negative = "-";
                input = Math.abs(input);
            }

            var s:String = input.toString();
            var results:Array = s.split(/\./);
            s = results[0];

            if ( s.length > 3 )
            {
                var mod:Number = s.length % 3;
                var output:String = s.substr(0, mod);
                for ( var i:Number = mod; i < s.length; i += 3 )
                {
                    output += ((mod == 0 && i == 0) ? "" : ",") + s.substr(i, 3);
                }

                if ( results.length > 1 )
                {
                    if ( results[1].length == 1 )
                        return negative + output + "." + results[1] + "0";
                    else
                        return negative + output + "." + results[1];
                }
                else
                    return negative + output;
            }
            if ( results.length > 1 )
            {
                if ( results[1].length == 1 )
                    return negative + s + "." + results[1] + "0";
                else
                    return negative + s + "." + results[1];
            }
            else
                return negative + s;
        }
    }
}
```

You can see a more detailed analysis at [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721304/insert-commas-into-number-string/13410560#13410560) but you can compare the compactness of each solution and weigh that against their accuracy and performance, however for the sake of brevity this solution is the most accurate and performant (though not the most compact):

```
public function commaify( input:Number ):String
{
    var split:Array = input.toString().split( '.' ),
        front:String = split[0],
        back:String = ( split.length > 1 ) ? "." + split[1] : null,
        n:int = input < 0 ? 2 : 1,
        commas:int = Math.floor( (front.length - n) / 3 ),
        i:int = 1;

    for ( ; i <= commas; i++ )
    {
        n = front.length - (3 * i + i - 1);
        front = front.slice( 0, n ) + "," + front.slice( n );
    }

    if ( back )
        return front + back;
    else
        return front;
}
```