# Java Programming - Need to insert commas

Tags: java, number-formatting

I'm just starting to learn java and need help with the basics. I wrote code that converts light speed to kilometers per second. The code looks like this:

```
public class LightSpeed
{
    private double conversion;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class LightSpeed
     */
    public LightSpeed()
    {
        conversion = (186000 * 1.6); //186000 is miles per second and 1.6 is kilometers per mile
    }

    /**
     * Print the conversion
     */
    public void conversion()
    {
        System.out.println("The speed of light is equal to " + conversion + " kilometers per second");
    }
}
```

I need the conversion to have commas in it so the number doesn't all run together. instead of the number looking like 297600.0 I need it to look like 297,600.0.  Someone please help! Thank you

Comment: Look up http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: See [Customizing Formats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

Comment: I think I know where you go to school.... :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert commas into number string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721304/insert-commas-into-number-string)

Answer (score 2):

You need to format the number.  One of the ways is with [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) in java.text.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0");
System.out.println("The speed of light is equal to " + df.format(conversion) + " kilometers per second");
```

Another way is with `printf`.  Use the comma flag and output one digit past the decimal point.  Here's [more about the flags for printf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

```
System.out.printf("The speed of light is equal to %,.1f kilometers per second\n", speed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your conversion method to

```
/**
 * Print the conversion
 */
public void conversion() {
    DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##");
    System.out.println("The speed of light is equal to "
            + myFormatter.format(conversion)
            + " kilometers per second");
}
```