# What do we need Lookahead/Lookbehind Zero Width Assertions for?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I've just learned about these two concepts in more detail. I've always been good with RegEx, and it seems I've never seen the need for these 2 zero width assertions.

I'm pretty sure I'm wrong, but I do not see why these constructs are needed. Consider this example:

```
Match a 'q' which is not followed by a 'u'.
```

2 strings will be the input:

```
Iraq
quit
```

With negative lookahead, the regex looks like this:

```
q(?!u)
```

Without it, it looks like this:

```
q[^u]
```

For the given input, both of these regex give the same results (i.e. matching `Iraq` but not `quit`) (tested with perl). The same idea applies to lookbehinds.

Am I missing a crucial feature that makes these assertions more valuable than the classic syntax?

Comment: What if I want to check if there is no `bar` after `foo`, this would lead to `foo[^b][^a][^r]` (and consumes it) which would be pretty easy with `foo(?!bar)` and somehow more readable. Also it may be handy in if/else regex statements

Comment: Do you use the `<`, or `>`, `\b` word boundary matches? They're shorthand for look-ahead, look-behind: `<` == `(?<!\w)(?=\w)`; `>` == `(?<=\w)(?!\w)` and `\b` == `(?:(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w))`. Although I'm guessing they are optimised for particular function.

Comment: A little bit offtopic: this question is now second in google for "iraq quit match"

Comment: Yes, I've used them before, especially word boundaries.

Comment: I write, on average, about five (Perl) regexes per day for one-liners using a custom-written [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/)-like (but faster) grep-tool over a 400Mb source base and I couldn't survive without look-ahead/look-behind.

Comment: @AdrianPronk You know what they say: "I had a problem, so I thought to use RegEx. Now I had 2 problems."

Comment: @0xCAFEBABE: It's like any powerful tool: you've got to know how to use it.  For example I find using [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) extremely daunting, but I'm sure there's experts out there who do all kinds of amazing work with it.

Comment: Also see [Insert commas into number string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/721415/41861)

Comment: @AdrianPronk An interesting example. I can see how the zero width assumptions solve this problem very elegantly. Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Why your test probably worked (and why it shouldn't)

The reason you were able to match `Iraq` in your test might be that your string contained a `\n` at the end (for instance, if you read it from the shell). If you have a string that ends in `q`, then `q[^u]` cannot match it as the others said, because `[^u]` matches a non-`u` character - but the point is there has to be a character.

### What do we actually need lookarounds for?

Obviously in the above case, lookaheads are not vital. You could workaround this by using `q(?:[^u]|$)`. So we match only if `q` is followed by a non-`u` character or the end of the string. There are much more sophisticated uses for lookaheads though, which become a pain if you do them without lookaheads.

This answer tries to give an overview of some important standard situations which are best solved with lookarounds.

Let's start with looking at quoted strings. The usual way to match them is with something like `"[^"]*"` (*not* with `".*?"`). After the opening `"`, we simply repeat as many non-quote characters as possible and then match the closing quote. Again, a negated character class is perfectly fine. But there are cases, where a negated character class doesn't cut it:

### Multi-character delimiters

Now what if we don't have double-quotes to delimit our substring of interest, but a multi-character delimiter. For instance, we are looking for `---sometext---`, where single and double `-` are allowed within `sometext`. Now you can't just use `[^-]*`, because that would forbid single `-`. The standard technique is to use a negative lookahead at every position, and only consume the next character, if it is not the beginning of `---`. Like so:

```
---(?:(?!---).)*---
```

This might look a bit complicated if you haven't seen it before, but it's certainly nicer (and usually more efficient) than the alternatives.

### Different delimiters

You get a similar case, where your delimiter is only one character but could be one of two (or more) different characters. For instance, say in our initial example, we want to allow for both single- and double-quoted strings. Of course, you could use `'[^']*'|"[^"]*"`, but it would be nice to treat both cases without an alternative. The surrounding quotes can easily be taken care of with a backreference: `(['"])[^'"]*\1`. This makes sure that the match ends with the same character it began with. But now we're too restrictive - we'd like to allow `"` in single-quoted and `'` in double-quoted strings. Something like `[^\1]` doesn't work, because a backreference will in general contain more than one character. So we use the same technique as above:

```
(['"])(?:(?!\1).)*\1
```

That is after the opening quote, before consuming each character we make sure that it is not the same as the opening character. We do that as long as possible, and then match the opening character again.

### Overlapping matches

This is a (completely different) problem that can usually not be solved at all without lookarounds. If you search for a match globally (or want to regex-replace something globally), you may have noticed that matches can never overlap. I.e. if you search for `...` in `abcdefghi` you get `abc`, `def`, `ghi` and not `bcd`, `cde` and so on. This can be problem if you want to make sure that your match is preceded (or surrounded) by something else.

Say you have a CSV file like

```
aaa,111,bbb,222,333,ccc
```

and you want to extract only fields that are entirely numerical. For simplicity, I'll assume that there is no leading or trailing whitespace anywhere. Without lookarounds, we might go with capturing and try:

```
(?:^|,)(\d+)(?:,|$)
```

So we make sure that we have the start of a field (start of string or `,`), then only digits, and then the end of a field (`,` or end of string). Between that we capture the digits into group `1`. Unfortunately, this will not give us `333` in the above example, because the `,` that precedes it was already part of the match `,222,` - and matches cannot overlap. Lookarounds solve the problem:

```
(?<=^|,)\d+(?=,|$)
```

Or if you prefer double negation over alternation, this is equivalent to

```
(?<![^,])\d+(?![^,])
```

In addition to being able to get all matches, we get rid of the capturing which can generally improve performance. (Thanks to Adrian Pronk for this example.)

### Multiple independent conditions

Another very classic example of when to use lookarounds (in particular lookaheads) is when we want to check multiple conditions on an input at the same time. Say we want to write a single regex that makes sure our input contains a digit, a lower case letter, an upper case letter, a character that is none of those, and no whitespace (say, for password security). Without lookarounds you'd have to consider all permutations of digit, lower case/upper case letter, and symbol. Like:

```
\S*\d\S*[a-z]\S*[A-Z]\S*[^0-9a-zA_Z]\S*|\S*\d\S*[A-Z]\S*[a-z]\S*[^0-9a-zA_Z]\S*|...
```

Those are only two of the 24 necessary permutations. If you also want to ensure a minimum string length in the same regex, you'd have to distribute those in all possible combinations of the `\S*` - it simply becomes impossible to do in a single regex.

Lookahead to the rescue! We can simply use several lookaheads at the beginning of the string to check all of these conditions:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^0-9a-zA-Z])(?!.*\s)
```

Because the lookaheads don't actually consume anything, after checking each condition the engine resets to the beginning of the string and can start looking at the next one. If we wanted to add a minimum string length (say `8`), we could simply append `(?=.{8})`. Much simpler, much more readable, much more maintainable.

*Important note:* This is **not** the best general approach to check these conditions in any real setting. If you are making the check programmatically, it's usually better to have one regex for each condition, and check them separately - this let's you return a much more useful error message. However, the above is sometimes necessary, if you have some fixed framework that lets you do validation only by supplying a single regex. In addition, it's worth knowing the general technique, if you ever have independent criteria for a string to match.

I hope these examples give you a better idea of why people would like to use lookarounds. There are a lot more applications (another classic is [inserting commas into numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721304/insert-commas-into-number-string/721415#721415)), but it's important that you realise that there is a difference between `(?!u)` and `[^u]` and that there are cases where negated character classes are not powerful enough at all.

Comment: Overlapping matches: extracting fields in a CSV line. For example, all numeric fields: `@numbers = 'aaa,111,bbb,222,ccc' =~ /(?<![^,])([^,]*)(?![^,])/g`.

Comment: @AdrianPronk thanks! I slightly modified it and used that instead.

Comment: @0xCAFEBABE added another very important usage scenario that I totally forgot about

Answer (score 5):

`q[^u]` will not match "Iraq" because it will look for another symbol.

`q(?!u)` however, will match "Iraq":

```
regex = /q[^u]/
/q[^u]/
regex.test("Iraq")
false
regex.test("Iraqf")
true
regex = /q(?!u)/
/q(?!u)/
regex.test("Iraq")
true
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, another thing along with what others mentioned with the negative lookahead, you can match consecutive characters (e.g. you can negate `ui` while with `[^...]`, you cannot negate `ui` but either `u` or `i` and if you try `[^ui]{2}`, you will also negate `uu`, `ii` and `iu`.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point is to not "consume" the next character(s), so that it can be e.g. captured by another expression that comes afterwards.

If they're the *last* expression in the regex, then what you've shown are equivalent.

But e.g. `q(?!u)([a-z])` would let the non-`u` character be part of the next group.