# Insert commas into a number through regex

Tags: regex

I have a regex to insert commas in an integer:

```
(?<=\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)
1829383839 ==> 1,829,383,839
```

This regex is also covered by the question: [Insert commas into number string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721304/insert-commas-into-number-string)

However, I'd also like to expand the regex to be able to do the commafication on decimal numbers. For example:

```
1829383839.2937484 ==> 1,829,383,839.2937484
```

How could this be done?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen anything. Most programming languages would have a trivial print function for this, for example `>>> f'{100000000.00:,}'` but trying to see how it could be done with regex.

Comment: You use the word "trivial," yet every programming language exposes a different regex API.  You never told us which one you are using, so...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen for this I'm just using https://regex101.com/ in PCRE mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

- Find: `(?:^|\G)(\d{1,3})(?=(\d{3})+(?:\.\d+)?$)`
- Replace: `$1,`

**Explanation:**

```
(?:^|\G)            # beginning of line or restart from last match posiiton
(\d{1,3})           # 1 to 3 digits
(?=                 # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    (\d{3})+            # 1 or more times 3 digits
    (?:\.\d+)?          # optional decimal places
    $                   # end of line
)                   # end lookahead
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/eP3EM8/3)

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to use [(*SKIP)(*FAIL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) to avoid matching the dot followed by digits.

```
\.\d+\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\d{1,3}(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.\d|(?!\S)))
```

In parts

- `\.\d+\b` Match a dot, 1+ digits and word boundary
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|` Match the characters that you want to avoid
- `\d{1,3}` Match 1-3 digits
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `(?:\d{3})+` Repeat 1+ times matching 3 digits
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `\.\d` Match a dot followed by a digit
    - `|` Or
    - `(?!\S)` Assert what is on the right is not a non whitespace char
  - `)` Close non capturing group
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rjJI4m/1)

In the replacement use the full match followed by a comma `$0,`

Comment: What does (*SKIP) and (*FAIL) do? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @user12283851They are [backtracking control verbs](https://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html)