# how to format number separated by comma for every three integer digits in presto

Tags: number-formatting, presto, trino

I want to format a number separated by comma for every three integer digits. for example 12345.894 -- > 12,345.894. I have no clue how to format it. I have tried for an example but no luck.

```
format('%,.2f', 12345.894)
```

The above code will round decimal to 2 digits so it returns 12,345.89. In my case, I want to keep the decimal 12,345.894.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use **regular expression**:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(cast(123456.8943 as VARCHAR), '(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)', '$1,')
  Results:
  -------
  123,456.8943
```

**Some explanation:**

First we cast to varchar as regex works on string.

The regex actually says: replace any digit `\d` you see only if it has one or more `+` groups of 3 digits `\d{3}` just before the "." (dot) sign `\.`. The digit is replaced by the same digit `$1` but with comma after it `,`.

The example can be seen [here](http://regexr.com/58c1m).

You can see more discussions on the regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721304/insert-commas-into-number-string).

Comment: Is there  a way to replicate this but truncate any decimal?

Answer (score 2):

If you want 3 decimal numbers you can use `%,.3f` as the format string:

```
presto> select format('%,.3f', 12345.894);
   _col0
------------
 12,345.894
(1 row)
```

Comment: no, I want to keep the decimal as is. for example 12345.87634 --> 12,345.87634, 12345.23476534 --> 12,345.2346534

Comment: There's no way to do that, unfortunately. The `%f` format specifier has a fixed number of decimals and defaults to 6. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#dndec

Comment: In my opinion, you can build the part of "3" dynamically and concat as the first parameter. e.g.,

select format('%,.' || cast(calculated_length as varchar) || 'f' ,value)