# Got stuck while using regular expression in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have try try use notepad++ for separate the character using comma, after 4 character.
but the output is not as expected.

output got:‭‭11,1111,1011,0011,1110,1111,1111,1111,11‬

expected output:‭‭1111,1110,1100,1111,1011,1111,1111,1111‬

I have attached an image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E2z3.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert commas into number string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721304/insert-commas-into-number-string)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how can i use in notepad++??

Comment: What about the input? Has '1' been a meta character in reg' exp's, that you write "\1" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^|\G)....\K`
- Replace with: `,`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:^|\G)    # non capture group, beginning of lien OR restart from last match position
....        # 4 any character but newline
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]