# Add big.mark = "," to texreg output

Tags: r, texreg

How do I add big.mark = "," to, say, the every column's number of observations or the number of clusters or the number of groups, etc to a texreg output? They all are or seem to be integer numbers, but each line can be identified by the entry in the first column (delimited in LaTeX with an `&`). For example, for the number of observations, the first column of that line contains `Num. obs.`

Here is a reproducible example:

```
# data sim
library(texreg)
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000)
y <- 5 + 2*x - z + rnorm(1000,0,40)/100
# regression
m1 <- lm(y~x)
summary(m1)
m2 <- lm(y~z)
summary(m2)
m3 <- lm(y~x+z)
summary(m3)
texreg(list(m1,m2,m2),
       caption = "Add big.marks, please!",
       label = NULL,
       model.names=c("M1","M2","M3"))
```

which generates the output:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c}
\hline
 & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 \\
\hline
(Intercept) & $5.02^{***}$ & $4.98^{***}$  & $4.98^{***}$  \\
            & $(0.04)$     & $(0.07)$      & $(0.07)$      \\
x           & $2.01^{***}$ &               &               \\
            & $(0.03)$     &               &               \\
z           &              & $-0.98^{***}$ & $-0.98^{***}$ \\
            &              & $(0.06)$      & $(0.06)$      \\
\hline
R$^2$       & $0.78$       & $0.19$        & $0.19$        \\
Adj. R$^2$  & $0.78$       & $0.18$        & $0.18$        \\
Num. obs.   & $1000$       & $1000$        & $1000$        \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\scriptsize{$^{***}p<0.001$; $^{**}p<0.01$; $^{*}p<0.05$}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Add big.marks, please!}
\label{}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I would like to add big.marks to the output, say, to the line that starts with `Num. obs.` (or any other line with large integer numbers) so it would look like

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c}
\hline
 & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 \\
\hline
(Intercept) & $5.02^{***}$ & $4.98^{***}$  & $4.98^{***}$  \\
            & $(0.04)$     & $(0.07)$      & $(0.07)$      \\
x           & $2.01^{***}$ &               &               \\
            & $(0.03)$     &               &               \\
z           &              & $-0.98^{***}$ & $-0.98^{***}$ \\
            &              & $(0.06)$      & $(0.06)$      \\
\hline
R$^2$       & $0.78$       & $0.19$        & $0.19$        \\
Adj. R$^2$  & $0.78$       & $0.18$        & $0.18$        \\
Num. obs.   & $1,000$      & $1,000$       & $1,000$       \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\scriptsize{$^{***}p<0.001$; $^{**}p<0.01$; $^{*}p<0.05$}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Added big.marks, thank you!}
\label{}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this package but a quick check of the [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/texreg/versions/1.38.6/topics/texreg) doesn't indicate an argument for adding a big mark. However, the output of `texreg()` is a character vector, so we can adapt this [Java regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721304/insert-commas-into-number-string) for R to add the big mark:

```r
tbl  <- texreg(list(m1,m2,m2),
       caption = "Add big.marks, please!",
       label = NULL,
       model.names=c("M1","M2","M3")) 

# Add big mark
tbl_big  <- gsub("(\\d)(?=(\\d{3}))", "\\1,", tbl, perl = TRUE)

# Remove extra space after the dollar so we keep alignment of ampersands
tbl_big  <- gsub("(\\$\\d+,\\d+\\$)\\s", "\\1", tbl_big)
```

This produces `tbl_big`:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c}
\hline
 & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 \\
\hline
(Intercept) & $5.02^{***}$ & $4.98^{***}$  & $4.98^{***}$  \\
            & $(0.04)$     & $(0.07)$      & $(0.07)$      \\
x           & $2.01^{***}$ &               &               \\
            & $(0.03)$     &               &               \\
z           &              & $-0.98^{***}$ & $-0.98^{***}$ \\
            &              & $(0.06)$      & $(0.06)$      \\
\hline
R$^2$       & $0.78$       & $0.19$        & $0.19$        \\
Adj. R$^2$  & $0.78$       & $0.18$        & $0.18$        \\
Num. obs.   & $1,000$      & $1,000$       & $1,000$       \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\scriptsize{$^{***}p<0.001$; $^{**}p<0.01$; $^{*}p<0.05$}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Add big.marks, please!}
\label{}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```